# How to prove if $A \subseteq B$ then $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$ using forward-backward method?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, predicate-logic

From "Introduction to Real Analysis (Dover books)" Exercise 1.15.1.g is to prove:

if $A \subseteq B$ then $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$

It indicates to use the forward backwards method. I an struggling to fill in the middle and unsure if I have formulated the conclusion correctly. Note that my comments for the backwards part relate to how the upper statement is derived from the lower statement.

$$A \subseteq B$$
$$(\forall x)(x \in A \implies x \in B) $$
$$\vdots$$

$$(\forall x)(((x \in B)  \land (x \in A)) \iff (x \in A)) $$

Removing the contradictory disjunct, removing double negation ^^

$$(\forall x)((((x \in B) \land \neg(x \in B)) \lor ((x \in B)  \land (\neg(\neg(x \in A))) \iff (x \in A)) $$

Distributing the disjunct over the conjunct ^^

$$(\forall x)(((x \in B) \land (\neg(x\in B) \lor \neg(\neg(x \in A))) \iff (x \in A)) $$

Processing the negated conjunction ^^

$$(\forall x)(((x \in B) \land\neg((x\in B) \land(\neg(x \in A))) \iff (x \in A)) $$
Conclusion:
   $$B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$$

It's not clear to me how to get from the premise to the the biconditional statement?

Also I wonder if there is a much simpler proof?

Also have I formulated  $B \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$ correctly?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the book you are using, but in my (limited) experience it is frowned upon to use the "$\in$" symbol to denote a subset.

Comment: In general, when referencing a book, you should mention title and author, maybe edition, not publisher. Dover in particular republished many old books. Also, make sure (as you did) that when referencing a book, you either re-state the relevant parts in the question (e.g. the problem), or provide a link to the book where someone could read it (i.e. don't send us to Amazon, but a PDF of the book; nobody is buying a textbook to answer your question).

Comment: You dont need quantifiers. It is obvious that if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$, no matter what $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to unwrap the definitions. For a subset $S$ of $B$, the set $B\setminus S$ is the collection of $x\in B$ that do *not* lie in $S$. Setting $B\setminus A=S$, we get $B\setminus (B\setminus A)$ is the collection of $x\in B$ that do *not* lie in $B\setminus A$. But an element of $B$ lies in $B\setminus A$ if and only if it lies in $B$ but not in $A$. Thus $B\setminus (B\setminus A)$ is the set of elemets of $B$ for which it is *not* true they do *not* lie in $A$. This is just the set of elements that do lie in $A$, which is $A$.

Comment: I understand the implication from an intuitive, verbal description. I am wondering how to use the backwards-forward method as indicated in the exercise though.

Comment: @BrendanHill The above is completely rigorous, albeit not formal. This method you're talking about probably means that to show that two sets $T,S$ are equal, it suffices to show $S$ is contained in $T$ and conversely. I did that, but using words. You'll profit more from being a clear user of words than from jamming symbols into paper!

Comment: can't argue with that.